# What is the correct way to disconnect this circuit board terminal?

Tags: connector, ribbon-cable

I've not been able to figure this out, nor have I been able to find out exactly what the terminal is. It's in an old 1989 Yamaha tape deck.

[image: Solderless terminal]

I have no idea how to actually remove it. I've tried pressing in the tabs at the side, I've tried splaying them out, I've tried levering a screwdriver under the tabs, nothing. I can't seem to pull it straight up because the ribbon cable is still trapped by it, and even if I get it past the little retaining notches the cable stops me moving it further. The amount of force needed is definitely excessive, so I'm clearly doing something wrong.

How can I disconnect the wire\connector from the board?

Comment: Are you able to press down on the upper piece of the connector - does it feel at all 'springy'? That might be a release mechanism for the contacts inside. Failing that I'd try to lever that top piece off, maybe a tiny flat screwdriver inserted into the space at each end...

Comment: nope, it's locked solid. Definitely not springy.
I've tried to lever it off, but I felt like I would snap something. It just wouldn't budge past a certain point, almost as if I was going to snap the wires.

Comment: Looks like there might be a little tab on each end which might push in to allow the top piece to be unlocked .... ?

Comment: Does the part on the top slide horizontally?

Comment: It doesn't slide horizontally as far as I can tell, and while I can get the top piece up slightly, it gets stuck on the cable shielding and it's impossible to go any higher without putting serious strain on the cable

Comment: Can you get to the bottom side of the PCB? If you desolder the entire connector it might help you figure out how the thing works.

Answer (score 2):

I would get a small flat screwdriver and carefully wedge it between the gaps on the sides.

I have encountered connectors like this that are actually not connectors, they are wire to board connections and can only be unsoldered. You can tell if it looks like there are wires soldered on the underside of the board or metal posts (both will be soldered, if it's a wire the bottom of the wire will have the same diameter as the top, a connector it's more likely to have a larger diameter).

Comment: I've tried that, but past a certain point it felt like I was putting far too much stress on the wire.
I'm fairly sure the wire isn't soldered, the PCB layouts of the board definitely are laid out in a manner akin to a connector

Comment: @jade Wedge a screwdriver on both ends simultaneously

Comment: Like I said in my post, I've encountered connectors that look like connectors but they aren't really connectors, they are wire to board connections and the plastic exists to provide strain relief. (I've also seen them mostly on low cost electronics) if you are lifting the connector and the wires aren't moving it's most likely that they are soldered to the board. One way to tell is to look down the connector and see if the wires have a crimp and even then they could be soldered in

Comment: This is on a Yamaha MT3X, which was a ~£600 tape mixer when it was new. It's definitely not a low cost device.
It seems weird that they would be soldered, the device is clearly designed to be taken apart for repair and servicing. The connector on the other end of the wire is definitely one that's board soldered, which again adds to my belief this is removable.
Even prising from both sides, the issue is the whole pcb starts to flex like it _really_ doesn't want to let go.

Comment: When I say low cost, I mean the PCB, it's single sided and FR1 or FR2. And they were definitely cost cutting, which is common in consumer electronics. Most consumer electronics are not built to be serviced or repaired, they are built to be thrown away.

Comment: This thing is over 30 years old, and was very much built to be serviced. I've read the service manual, it definitely implies this connector can be removed to replace the daughter board wholesale.

Comment: I'm not saying you can't remove it, I'm just sharing my own experience with consumer electronics. If the manual says it can be removed then it can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

The top ring looks like it might hinge, with the bottom right corner (opposite the 10 on the circuit board) being the pivot point. There is probably a hook at the 2 top corners opposite the pivot. Use 2 pin tools or tiny screwdrivers to release the hooks as you do the pivot.

Comment: Everything seems solid, the only movement is if I lift the outer ring section upwards.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're suggesting, I've not tried that approach yet.
I've reassembled it for the time being, but once some spare parts come in I'll give that a shot.